# search on Google returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: 17.04, dns, google

I've installed ubuntu gnome 17.04 on my laptop and I can't search on Google.
I can use others search engine and they work, if I ping a website he will respond.
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use different DNS try using the public DNS of google.

Open dhclient config.
`sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Set the new DNS.
`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

Restart Network service
`sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I set a new setting of DNS, and i tried to delete cache, but he doesn't find command.

Comment: Sorry i forgot this is ubuntu try this instead :) check my edited post.

Comment: Yes, I tried to switch off PC with no results

Comment: I'm pretty sure my last edit should fix this for you

Comment: I tried also that, but he doesn't solve it.

Comment: It's a dns problem just change the dns via network manager gui or whatever network manager you use and it will fix your problem

Comment: I forgot to explain that i've replaced ubuntu 15.04 with this version, and on the previous OS i haven't this kind of problems.

Comment: you should clear cache and change dns to fix your problem, sorry i can't help you anymore right now